# Repeatable random sort on SQL-Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I was wondering if anyone knew of how to perform a repeatable random sort on MS SQL Server.

I have achieve the same on other DB Platforms via setting a seed value on the random function:

```
MySQL/MariaDB: ORDER BY RAND(?);
Oracle: EXEC DBMS_RANDOM.SEED(?); ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE;
Postgres: SELECT SETSEED(?); ORDER BY RANDOM();
```

However, I can't find the equivalent on SQL-Server.
Doing some research, I tried the syntax TABLESAMPLE(100 PERCENT) REPEATABLE(Y). But TABLESAMPLE doesn't seem to give me the rows back in any random order.

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d50dd/30

Comment: Doing `ORDER BY(RAND(id))` should be giving you a repeatable random order across queries and even across database sessions.  What is the problem then?

Comment: `ORDER BY RAND(id)` doesn't randomize on this DB Platform. Because `RAND()` is seeded once during the SELECT query, so it is the value on every row. The correct way to randomize on SQL-Server is to use `ORDER BY NEWID();` which ensures a new value on every row, but you can't seed that function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably not the best solution for large tables, but it will work for most smaller tablesets.

`ORDER BY RIGHT(STR(RAND(id + seed), 18, 18), 1);`

Explanation on what this does:

- We generate a random float value based on the row_id + seed value passed. This float value is 18 digits in length.
- Convert the random float value to a string which lets us use T-SQL native string functions on the value.
- Use the T-SQL RIGHT() function to grab the last digit of the random float value. USE that to ORDER by.

I am not sure how performance will be, but I anticipate this to be pretty average to bad for large data sets.

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d50dd/95